# How to replace smarty tags with regex

Tags: regex, command-line, sed, smarty

i want to replace smarty tags with SED, but i cant overcome this problem

**This is what i got so far:**

```
echo "This {$is} a test to replace a tag" | sed -e 's/\\{\$is\\}/was/g'
```

**This is the result of the previous command:**

```
This {} a test to replace a tag
```

**This is what i actually want to archive a simple replacement of {$tags}**

```
This was a test to replace a tag
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Likely you're using bash which is seeing the `$is` and trying to replace it as a variable. If you enclose your string in single quotes, it will be treated as a literal. Also, you've added a whole bunch of extra escapes to your regex expression. `echo 'This {$is} a test to replace a tag' | sed -e 's/{$is}/was/'` will return what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

use simple quote (with double quote `$is` is replaced by the content of the bash variable $is, ie '') :

```
echo 'This {$is} a test to replace a tag' | sed 's/{$is}/was/g'
```